# Create flask modules and divide the application

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a small flask application and I want to have a modular structure in my project.

In Django I could just write two separate folders with their own `urls.py`, register them in my `settings.py` and create routes to them in base `urls.py`.

How to achieve this kind of modularity in flask?
Preferably with as little code as possible.

Bonus points if all this can be easily done without extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/).

```
app.py
blueprints/
    sample_blueprint.py
    another_blueprint.py
```

Blueprints are like apps but not apps. (very lame explanation but let me show you some code)

```
# sample_blueprint.py
from flask import Blueprint

# just like `app = Flask(__name__)`
SAMPLE_BLUEPRINT = Blueprint('sample_blueprint', __name__)

# just like `@app.route('/sample')`
@SAMPLE_BLUEPRINT.route('/sample')
def sample():
    return 'Sample'
```

And then in `app.py` you have to register it.

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask

from blueprints.sample import SAMPLE_BLUEPRINT


app = Flask(__name__)

# Register all the blueprints, url_prefix is optional
app.register_blueprint(SAMPLE_BLUEPRINT, url_prefix='/sample-br')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

You can now run the app (`python3 app.py`) and goto [localhost:5000/sample-br/sample](http://localhost:5000/sample-br/sample) and see the response of the blueprint route.

This code is not tested. It is just to give you a starting idea. Please read the docs and try it out on your own and find out how blueprints fit into a Flask project.